# How can i show data in recyclerview using response data

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have a recyclerview, i want to show data via retrofit. But i can't because this data type is response,recyclerview need list.

GetApi.kt

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
suspend fun getNews(
    @Query("apiKey") apikey: String
):Response<NewsData>
```

ArticleAdapter.kt

```
class ArticleAdapter (private val onItemClickListener: ArticleOnItemClickListener): 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private var articleList = emptyList<NewsData>()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.article_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.article_headline.text = articleList[position].title
    holder.itemView.article_author.text = articleList[position].author
    holder.itemView.article_date.text = articleList[position].publishedAt
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(articleList[position].urlToImage).into(holder.itemView.article_image)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClickListener.onClick(articleList[position],position)
    }

}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return articleList.size
}

fun setData(newList: List<Article>) {
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    articleList = newList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

How can i show response data in a recyclerview?Thank you

Comment: Provide the data class for NewsData and Article plus the calling of getNews.

Comment: Yeah, or the JSON response you're getting.

Comment: Can you both more explain?

Comment: Sorry it's not article list,it's a NewsData list.i edited my adpater code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Call without suspend:

```
interface Api {
    @GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
    fun getNews(
        @Query("apiKey") apikey: String,
    ): Call<NewsData>
}
```

Mapper:

```
class NewsDataToArticles : (NewsData) -> List<Article>{
    override fun invoke(p1: NewsData): List<Article> {
        // TODO: Write a mapper
        return listOf()
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class ArticleAdapter(private val onItemClickListener: ArticleOnItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var articleList = emptyList<Article>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.article_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.article_headline.text = articleList[position].title
        holder.itemView.article_author.text = articleList[position].author
        holder.itemView.article_date.text = articleList[position].publishedAt
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(articleList[position].urlToImage)
            .into(holder.itemView.article_image)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener.onClick(articleList[position], position)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    fun setData(newList: List<Article>) {
        articleList = newList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Retrofit:

```
fun retrofitService(): Api {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(// Base URL)
        .addConverterFactory(// Json Builder)
        .client(// OkHttp Client)
        .build()
        .create(Api::class.java)
}
```

Activity method:

```
class Activity{
    fun onCreate(){
        val mapper = NewsDataToArticles()
        // TODO: Remove apiKey and transfer it to okHttp interceptor
        val call : Call<NewsData> = retrofitService().getNews("apiKey")
        val adapter = ArticleAdapter()// put a listener

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        call.enqueue(object: Callback<NewsData>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsData>, response: Response<NewsData>) {
               if(response.isSuccessful){
                   val articles = response.body()?.let { mapper(it) }

                   adapter.setData(articles)
               }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsData>, t: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: I am using mvvm and livedata,how can i achieve this?

Comment: Sorry it's not a article list it's NewsData list.i edited my list in adapter but problem is same